# Как объединить 4 диалоговых окна в 1?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qdialog

У меня есть **`4`** диалоговых окна, которые просят пользователя ввести данные и этими данными заполняется новая строка в таблице.

Вопрос: Как мне их объединить в **`1`** единое диалоговое окно ?

```
def add_new_row(self):
        window = QWidget()
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

        text, done = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'ip :')
        text1, done1 = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'Организация :')
        text2, done2 = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'Улица :')
        text3, done3 = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'Город :')
        # text, text1, text2, text3, done = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'ip :', 'Место :', 'Улица :', 'Город :')
            
        if done and done1 and done2 and done3:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text1))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text2))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text3))

        else: pass
```

`Ui_Form` вызывалась кнопкой, попытался вывести, но из за ошибки -

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MyWin "Form", which alredy has a layout

вернул в изначалный вид.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
    QInputDialog, QApplication)
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QHeaderView
import sqlite3


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form): 
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(606, 335)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "ip"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Место"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Улица"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Город"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Изменить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Удалить"))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #fa7f72;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")

        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)

        self.row_count = 1
        self.table_index = 0

        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect("New.db")
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT ip, Location, Yi, Gor FROM ips"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        
        for row in records:
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(self.row_count)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[2])))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(self.table_index, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[3])))

            self.table_index += 1
            self.row_count += 1

        cursor.close()
        sqlite_connection.close()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_new_row)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clear_item)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.edit_item)

    def add_new_row(self):
        window = QWidget()
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

        text, done = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'ip :')
        text1, done1 = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'Организация :')
        text2, done2 = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'Улица :')
        text3, done3 = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'Город :')
        # text, text1, text2, text3, done = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Input Dialog', 'ip :', 'Место :', 'Улица :', 'Город :')
            
        if done and done1 and done2 and done3:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text1))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text2))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text3))

        else: pass

    def clear_item(self):
        pass

    def edit_item(self):
        pass
```

---

Вызов:

```
def setings_ip_window(self):
        window = setings_ip_window(self)
        window.show()

class setings_ip_window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=MyWin):
        super(setings_ip_window, self).__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.setings_ip = Ui_Form()
        self.setings_ip.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(2)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил. И как мне управлять Ui_form из другого файла, попробовал также как и с QMainWindow, но она не реагировала (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать свой диалог от `QDialog`

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QWidget, QFormLayout, QVBoxLayout, QDialogButtonBox, QLineEdit


class InputCorporateDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')

        self.line_edit_ip = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_corporate = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_street = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_city = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('IP:', self.line_edit_ip)
        form_layout.addRow('Организация:', self.line_edit_corporate)
        form_layout.addRow('Улица:', self.line_edit_street)
        form_layout.addRow('Город:', self.line_edit_city)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)


app = QApplication([])

window = QWidget()

dialog = InputCorporateDialog(window)
if dialog.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
    print(dialog.line_edit_ip.text())
    print(dialog.line_edit_corporate.text())
    print(dialog.line_edit_street.text())
    print(dialog.line_edit_city.text())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

```
1123
Рога и Копыта
Кукуева
Т
```

---

**PS.** Вместо `QLineEdit` можно использовать другие виджеты, это просто пример.

Comment: А как мне его вызвать нажатием кнопки ?

Comment: Или мб его как-то сигналом вызывать ?

Comment: @OverNiko, да, можно вызывать его внутри функции

Answer (score 2):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный Qt Designer - **НИКОГДА** . Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form): 
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(606, 335)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #54e346;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "ip"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Место"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Улица"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Город"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Изменить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #00b8ef;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Удалить"))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: #fa7f72;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: #626AB0;\n"
"    background-color: #D5D4D4;\n"
"}")

    
class InputCorporateDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Input Dialog')

        self.line_edit_ip = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_corporate = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_street = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_city = QLineEdit()

        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow('IP:', self.line_edit_ip)
        form_layout.addRow('Организация:', self.line_edit_corporate)
        form_layout.addRow('Улица:', self.line_edit_street)
        form_layout.addRow('Город:', self.line_edit_city)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(button_box)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_new_row)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clear_item)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.edit_item)
        
        # Здесь ваша логика 
       
    def add_new_row(self):
        inputDialog = InputCorporateDialog()
        rez = inputDialog.exec()
        if not rez:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Диалог сброшен.')
            return
        
        text = inputDialog.line_edit_ip.text()
        text1 = inputDialog.line_edit_corporate.text()
        text2 = inputDialog.line_edit_street.text()
        text3 = inputDialog.line_edit_city.text()
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        if text and text1 and text2 and text3:        
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text1))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text2))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition , 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(text3))
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните все поля.')

    def clear_item(self):
        pass

    def edit_item(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(450, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я понимаю, что нельзя изменять код QtDesigner, но как я и сказал ранее - пробовал управлять Ui-Form также как и QMainWindow, но она не реагировала

Comment: @OverNiko вы пробовали мой пример? Он вам помог?

Comment: Да, как всегда - спасибо

Comment: И ещё вопросик по вызову, я разделил всё на разные файлы, раньше вызывал Ui_Form кнопкой так (прикрепил), как теперь вызывать ? Новый файл этой таблицы Main_setings_ip (код QtDesigner в другом)

Comment: @OverNiko Задайте новый вопрос, прикрепите код, опишите проблему и я конечно попробую посмотреть как ее решить.